# How to remove item from Redis sorted set based on json filed

Tags: java, kotlin, redis, social-networking

I'm using redis to design user timeline (as in tweeter). I'm using sorted set to store json value with timestamp as score

```
 zrange feed:user:10000001 0 10 WITHSCORES
 1) "{\"postId\":10000411,\"userId\":10000001}"
 2) "1639073241754"
 3) "{\"postId\":10000412,\"userId\":10000002}"
 4) "1639073241748"
```

When user A unfollow B, how do I remove all posts of user B from timeline of user A?

As querying the json data is not supported in sorted set (and redis), Oher responses on SO suggested to store json value in hash having `postId` as subkey and storing `postId` as value in sorted set. but then where do I store `userId` to look for it when deleting based on it? How do I implement this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should completely refactor the way you're storing data. I suggest this way:

1. having a sorted set of  `feed:user:{userId}` which only store postId.
2. having a set of `user:post:{userId}` which store set of user's postId

So in order to "remove all posts of user B from timeline of user A", you need to first perform a query of like `redis> SMEMBERS user:post:{userBId}` to retrieve all B's postId and store it into a variable "`results`" and then perform this command `ZREM feed:user:{userAId} results`

Comment: Excellent. This solves my use case. However, curios to know if this can cause issue if user b has large number of posts, because we only need to remove user B's posts that are in timeline of user A (say 10-15), not every post of user B (say 100-1000)

Comment: @Annon Generally no! (actually I work on a similar application which we treat like this) but if you've already store user's post in anywhere,like a postgresql table, you can retrieve userB's  posts id and fill `results` from there. I mean for storing a user's timeline you only need post ids, not anything else.